# How to evaluate LightGBM in R using cohen's kappa?

Tags: r, xgboost, lightgbm

I use XGBoost in R on a regular basis and want to start using LightGBM on the same data. My goal is to use cohen's kappa as evaluation metric. However, I am not able to properly implement LightGBM - it seems that no learning occurs. As a very simple example, I'll use the titanic dataset.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)

titanic <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcsanwald/kaggle-titanic/master/train.csv")

titanic_complete <- titanic %>%
   select(survived, pclass, sex, age, sibsp, parch, fare, embarked) %>% 
   mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) %>%
   mutate(survived = as.factor(survived)) %>% 
   na.omit()

train_class <- titanic_complete %>% 
   select(survived) %>% 
   pull()

train_numeric <- titanic_complete %>% 
   select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
   data.matrix()

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "none", search = "grid")

tune_grid_xgbTree <- expand.grid(
   nrounds = 700,
   eta = 0.1,
   max_depth = 3,
   gamma = 0,
   colsample_bytree = 0,
   min_child_weight = 1,
   subsample = 1)

 set.seed(512)
 fit_xgb <- train(
    x = train_numeric,
    y = train_class,
    tuneGrid = tune_grid_xgbTree,
    trControl = ctrl,
    method = "xgbTree",
    metric = "Kappa",
    verbose = TRUE)

 confusionMatrix(predict(fit_xgb, train_numeric), train_class)
```

Gives me a Kappa of 0.57 evaluated on the training set (which is only to show my problem, otherwise I would use cross-validation).

For LightGBM, I write Kappa as a custom evaluation function:

```
library(lightgbm)
lgb.kappa <- function(preds, y) {
   label <- getinfo(y, "label")
   k <- unlist(e1071::classAgreement(table(label, preds)))["kappa"]
   return(list(name = "kappa", value = as.numeric(k), higher_better = TRUE))
 }

X_train <- titanic_complete %>% select(-survived) %>% data.matrix()
y_train <- titanic_complete %>% select(survived) %>% data.matrix()
y_train <- y_train - 1

dtrain <- lgb.Dataset(data = X_train, label = y_train)
```

Here, I use the same parameter set than in XGBoost but I tried different combinations without success.

```
fit_lgbm <- lgb.train(data = dtrain,
                  objective = "binary",
                  learning_rate = 0.1,
                  nrounds = 700,
                  colsample_bytree = 0,
                  eval = lgb.kappa,
                  min_child_weight = 1,
                  max_depth = 3)
```

No learning occurs and the algorithm outputs "No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf" and Kappa = 0.

If someone hast successfully implemented LightGBM (maybe with a custom evaluation metric), I would be very happy for a hint of how to resolve this.

Answer (score 4):

> No learning occurs and the algorithm outputs "No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf"

This is because [LightGBM's default parameter values](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#learning-control-parameters) are configured for larger datasets. The training dataset in your example above only has 714 rows. To deal with this, I recommend setting LightGBM's parameters to values that permit smaller leaf nodes, and limiting the number of leaves instead of the depth.

```r
list(
    "min_data_in_leaf" = 3
    , "max_depth" = -1
    , "num_leaves" = 8
)
```

> and Kappa = 0.

I believe your implementation of Cohen's kappa has a mistake. The input to `e1071::classAgreement()` is expected to be a table of *counts* (a confusion matrix), and `preds` is in the form of predicted probabilities. I think this implementation is correct, based on [the description of this metric on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa).

```r
lgb.kappa <- function(preds, dtrain) {
    label <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
    threshold <- 0.5
    thresholded_preds <- as.integer(preds > threshold)
    k <- unlist(e1071::classAgreement(table(label, thresholded_preds)))["kappa"]
    return(list(name = "kappa", value = as.numeric(k), higher_better = TRUE))
}
```

Finally, I think 700 iterations is probably too many for a 700ish-observation dataset. You can see the value of metrics evaluated against the training data at each iteration by passing the training data as a validation set.

Taken together, I think the code below accomplishes what the original question asked for.

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(lightgbm)

titanic <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcsanwald/kaggle-titanic/master/train.csv")

titanic_complete <- titanic %>%
    select(survived, pclass, sex, age, sibsp, parch, fare, embarked) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) %>%
    mutate(survived = as.factor(survived)) %>% 
    na.omit()

train_class <- titanic_complete %>% 
    select(survived) %>% 
    pull()

train_numeric <- titanic_complete %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
    data.matrix()

lgb.kappa <- function(preds, dtrain) {
    label <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
    threshold <- 0.5
    thresholded_preds <- as.integer(preds > threshold)
    k <- unlist(e1071::classAgreement(table(label, thresholded_preds)))["kappa"]
    return(list(name = "kappa", value = as.numeric(k), higher_better = TRUE))
}

X_train <- titanic_complete %>% select(-survived) %>% data.matrix()
y_train <- titanic_complete %>% select(survived) %>% data.matrix()
y_train <- y_train - 1

# train, printing out eval metrics at ever iteration
fit_lgbm <- lgb.train(
    data = lgb.Dataset(
        data = X_train,
        label = y_train
    ),
    params = list(
        "min_data_in_leaf" = 3
        , "max_depth" = -1
        , "num_leaves" = 8
    ),
    objective = "binary",
    learning_rate = 0.1,
    nrounds = 10L,
    verbose = 1L,
    valids = list(
        "train" = lgb.Dataset(
            data = X_train,
            label = y_train
        )
    ),
    eval = lgb.kappa,
)

# evaluate a custom function after training
fit_lgbm$eval_train(
    feval = lgb.kappa
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Somehow, the documentation on the R API is lacking compared to the Python API, and your answer was very useful. Only suggestion would be to use the method `get_field` instead, since `getinfo` is deprecated.